# How to calculate distance from accelerometer

Tags: algorithm, embedded

I am a beginner in embedded world. Currently I am working on MPU9250 motion sensor. My objective of project is to calculate the distance in real time using accelerometer. e.g. If I am at point A (i.e located at 5cm on X-axis) and I am willing to move towards point B (i.e. located at 50cm on X-axis) then the movement from A->B should show changes in distance as 5,6,7,---10---50 cm. Similarly movement from B->A should show changes in distance as 50,49,48----30,29,----5 cm.

My project is very generic and it is to be implemented on embedded processor, so I don't need any costlier algorithm like kalmaan etc. I had gone through many forums for accomplishing this task. I am using double Integration and also filtering the noise and managing the drift as well.

The issue I am currently facing is that, I am getting data , which varies even when the sensor stand still. Due to which the final estimated distance is getting change continuously. Also when I move the sensor the overall estimated displacement is coming out to be very low. Please suggest me some direction to eliminate the issue.

Currently my displacement algorithm is:

```
V[t] = V[t-1] + (A[t]+A[t-1])*T/2  // Where T is my sampling interval set by RTOS. 100msec
Pos[t] = Pos[t-1] + (V[t]+V[t-1])*T/2
```

Comment: @Lundin I missed that. The cumulative error is still too high. All I can think of is perhaps an optical mouse style camera, or a cheap range finder. Or a higher resolution sensor and faster polling intervals. 100ms is pretty sparse.

Comment: @JasonC I'm not really an expert of these things, but I believe the most common method is to use 3 axis accelerometer together with a gyro. Supposedly there are tiny MEMS circuits containing all of that in one single chip.

Answer (score 2):

The estimated position from accelerometer is calculated by double integration of acceleration, so the integral error's supposed to be added to integration result.

This issue can be solved by INS/GPS fusion(outdoor) or LPE(Local Position Estimation) Sensor.

If only Z-axis position is needed, barometer + accelerometer would be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple high pass filters to remove tiny offsets and gravitation bias that will accumulate horribly when integrating. That means quick movements well mostly come through but slow movements will be lost in the high pass filters. You need low pass filters to get rid of noise. That will cause quick movements to be mostly lost. What’s left is not very good except for a narrow range of velocities you might be able to tune for.
I saw some suggestion other using an FFT and doing the filtering in the frequency domain has some advantages but I’ve never tried it.
Combining with other sensors with different advantages through a Kalman filter or etc is often used.